# Android: Will the phone camera resolution affect the result of preprocessing

Tags: android, image, image-processing, opencv

My current project is about android image processing.But if my phone camera is about 1-2 megapixel, will it affect the result of preprocessing like grayscale and binarization?

Comment: It depends. If you have blurry images and many noises, for sure you will need extra pre-processing.

Comment: I will do preprocessing for every image.But my problem is because of my phone camera is 1-2 megapixel, so the photo that I take does not has good quality,so will it affect the result of preprocessing?

Comment: I don't think 1 megapixel does not have good quality if compared to vga(0.3mp == 640x480) resolution. As I said, there are many other factors that will affects the results.

Comment: @MizukiKai, you means phone camera resolution will not affect the result of preprocessing?My problem is after preprocess the image (grayscale and binarize),the image result is quite blur.Since the brightness of image is one of the factor that will affect the result,so megapixel does not affect the result of image?

Comment: The more resolution you have, the more details you got. It doesn't have anything to do with blurs. Blurs happen when you have some object moves fast (try short exposure time).

Comment: Since my phone camera is fixed focus,will it affect the result of image?

Comment: Automatic focus is done where you want the particular area to be more clearer. What are you trying to do here anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phone camera won't affect any pre-processing you perform in that your pre-processing code will act just the same regardless of the number of megapixels in your camera. Garbage in, garbage out still does apply. If you start with a low quality, poor contrast, blurred picture, you aren't going to be able to turn it in to something fantastic you want to hang on your wall. Additionally, as Mizuki alluded to in his comment, a 1-2 megapixel phone image is far higher resolution than the average image used on the internet, and these can be binarised and greyscaled just fine.

As for the two methods of preprocessing you mentioned in your question:

**Binarization**

This just converts an image into a two colour version. Normally black and white, though other colours are possible. The number of pixels in the image doesn't matter for this, other than it taking longer if it has more pixels to process. Low quality mobile phone cameras can sometimes produce low contrast photos and this may make it harder for the binarization algorithm to correctly determine the threshold at which pixels should be displayed in either colour.

**Greyscale**

Converting an image to greyscale is done by manipulating the colours of each pixel so, again, the number of pixels should only increase the preprocessing time, not change the result.